# Help with simple mod_rewrite needed

Tags: regex, apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

My site uses mod_rewrite for most URL's within the site.
eg.

`domain.com/contact.htm`

`domain.com/product/details.htm`

I've had `domain.com/contact.htm` working for a long time and is quite simple, but unfortunately I cannot for the life of me  get subfolder rewrites working so that I can go to `domain.com/product1/about.htm` without it taking me straight to a 404 page.
Here is an excerpt from my .htaccess.

```
RewriteRule ^product1/([^/]+).htm$ /product1/index.php?p=$1 [L] #Even hardcoded isn't working...
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+).htm$ /$1/$2/index.php?p=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+).htm$ /$1/index.php?p=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+).htm$ /index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

These rules work fine on http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/ but never seem to work in practice. I'd love some help on this.

***Edit:*** FYI, this is a singular .htaccess file located in the root www folder of domain.com.

Thanks.

Comment: Are those all of your rules? You might have conflicting rules somewhere.

Comment: Yes, these are all of the rules I use.

Comment: Perhaps this question belongs on [webmasters.se]?

Answer (score 1):

D'oh!.... Ok, apache obviously didn't like me having a .htaccess file within the subfolder with `RewriteEngine On` even though there weren't any rules. I removed the `RewriteEngine On` and it worked. Bam. 2 Evenings gone.

Thanks anyway guys.